# Issues In Angular Navigation and Modules

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I have in my Angular page a button called **"Process Loan"**. When an employee clicks this button, he comes to another page which has three links. Each of these 3 links leads to a separate page where the user can fill in a form and send it to the server. These 3 pages containing the forms are Angular components inside a module (lets call it **"my-process-loan-module"**). It means that when a user clicks on the **"Process Loan"** button he comes inside a module that has 3 components. Each component is a form.

The challenge I am facing now is there are a lot of employees and we want to make sure only one employee can access the **"Process Loan"** button at a time. When an employee clicks on the button, it must be disabled for other employees.

The first employee who clicks on the **"Process Loan"** button could be navigating the 3 pages/components even without filling the forms. As long as he/she is inside any of the pages, no other employee can access the **"Process Loan"** button.

I have studied `canDeActivate` in Angular but it seems it only works for components. I am looking if it is possible to do `canDeActivate` for Angular modules (since the 3 components (pages) are inside a module) so that when the first employee exits the module (navigating away from the components inside the module) I can reactivate the **"Process Loan"** button for the other employees.

I am looking for a way to determine that the first employee is going to a page that is not part of the pages(components) inside the ***"my-process-loan-module"***.

### Update

On the server I set a boolean that the **"Process Loan"** button is **inactive** when the first employee clicks on the button. I need to know when the employee exits the pages in the module so that I can enable the status to **active** for other employees who would like to use the **"Process Loan"** button.

Comment: All of the logic you are describing here needs to be on the server-side, because it needs to affect everyone connected to the app.

Comment: @WillAlexander the post is updated

Comment: Add logic to the `ngOnDestroy` of the appropriate component, telling the server that the component has been closed.

Comment: What does your server look like? Are there several copies of your server running? What your options are depends partially on how your back-end is built.

Answer (score 0):

When a user navigates away from a given component, that component's `ngOnDestroy()` method is called. Place any required destruction logic in there.

EDIT: If you need to be sure it is fired even if the user closes the window, add the `@HostListener('window:beforeunload')` decorator.